# Desktop application which can work offline when no connectivity with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am designing a WPF desktop application and using Entity framework Code First to create and use SQL Server Database. My database will be hosted on One Server machine and will be running 24*7.

I want to provide a feature, where you can modify data offline(when you have no connectivity with SQL Server DB) and Save it somehow. And whenever your application will find connection with SQL Server, all changes can be moved to SQL Server DB.

Is there any way to achieve this by using Entity Framework ? 
I want to emphasis on the part that I am using **Entity Framework**. Is this type of functionality already implemented by EF?? Or I have to do it manually, like have to write that in any file system and then manually merge it later to DB ?

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you just looking to have someone send documentation/tutorials your way?

Comment: No database access--where's the data to change?

Comment: @Hank, I just started looking. Checking to see if there is anything already available ? Or if there is any feature of Entity Framework which I can use

Comment: @LorenPechtel No DB access will be temporary. So if I am working offline, and when I connect back to DB, it will write all the offline changes to DB

Comment: You missed my question--if you have no DB where do you get the data you're seeking to change?

Comment: @LorenPechtel I am thinking whenever user will run the app, it will take a snapshot of the DB (Entire or user specific) which can be used offline. Just thinking. I cant think of any other way than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could figure out the specific exceptions that are generated when the SQL Server connection is lost, and embed your calls in try-catch blocks.  If the server is offline, then in your catch block, pass the entity to a method that serializes the entity to JSON and saves it to the hard drive in a special directory or something.  On your next successful query, check that directory to see if there are any saved entities that need to be saved.

Be specific with your catches - you don't want unrelated exceptions to trigger this code.

Some things to keep in mind - what if somebody else changed the data in the meantime?  Are you intending to overwrite those changes?  How did you get the data which needs to be saved in the first place if you are offline?

Comment: I like the idea of doing it in Try catch and saving it in JSON file and read it back. So you are saying once I read JSON, I will have it data in my domain class context and I can write it to DB using Entity framework .Save() method? Because Entity Framework has its own way to keep track of changes and save them. How will it detect those changes ?

Comment: You are right, and I'm rusty with EF, but I imagine you would have to do one of two things: Option 1 would be to "save" enough additional info for your code to reproduce the original EF select query (I was unable to save the changes I made to Employee #381, so I need to select #381 again, then make the same changes I was trying to, then save the result.)  Option 2 would be to use some good old-fashioned T-SQL to do the same thing that the EF would have done (write a separate SQL statement to update employee #381 and any child objects while maintaining data consistency.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have all data loaded into DbContext/ObjectContext you're free to amend those data anyway you want. Only when SaveChanges() is invoked, the connection is really needed.

However, if you're going to load everything into the context, you seem to reimplementing DataSet functionality, which, in addition, allows for xml serialization/deserialization of the changes, so the changes can be even saved between sessions.

Not as trendy as EF, though :)

Comment: Loading in DBContext can only work if application is running. But as per my application requirement, we might close application and run it later and then do some modification offline.

Comment: @Mini, you're right, you need data loaded. This is why I mentioned DataSet which allows for xml-based persistence as well as database operations.

You might want to look for some kind of cacheing layer for EF (sorry, no idea wherever it is available) which allows for cross-session persistence.

Or, if you redesign your all to use an embedded database, like SQL Server Compact with replication to big brother, you might achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

While I have never tried this with SQL-based data I have done it in the past with filesystem-based data and it's a major can of worms.

First, you have to have some means of indicating what data needs to be stored locally so that it will be available when you're offline.  This will need to be updated either all the time or before you head out--and that can involve a lot of data transfer.

Second, once you're back online there's a lot of conflict resolution that must be done.  If there's a realistic chance that someone else might have changed the data while you were out you need some way of detecting the conflict and prompting the user as to what to do in that situation.  This almost certainly requires a system that keeps a detailed edit trail on every unit of data that could reasonably be updated.

In my situation I was very fortunate in that it was virtually certain that if the remote user edited file [x] that overwriting the system copy was the right thing to do.  Remote users would only be carrying the files that pertained to their projects, conflicts should never happen.  Thus the writeback was simply based on timestamps, nothing more.  Data which people in the field would not normally need to modify was handled by not even looking at it, modified files were simply copied from the system to the laptop.

This leaves the middle step--saving the pending writes.  I disagree with Elemental Pete's answer in this regard--simply serializing them and saving the result them does **not** work because what happens when you read that data back in again?  You see the old copy, not the changed copy!

My approach to this was a local store of all relevant data that was accessed exactly like the main system data was, all reads and writes worked normally.

Something a lot fancier might be needed if you have data that needs transactions involved.

Note that we also hit a nasty human problem: the update process took several minutes (note: >10y ago) simply analyzing what needed to be done, not counting any actual copy time.  The result was people bypassing it when they thought they could.  Sometimes they thought wrong, oops!